# How do I run an install task as another user in install4j?

Tags: install4j

My installer needs to be run as root, and will need to shell out as another user to start some processes.  This seems like a task that many install builders would need. What is the best way to do that in install4j?  I don't see an action that covers it and when I try to wrap 'su' around a command in a "Run Executeable or batch file" tasks it doesn't seem to be able to run shell builtins like su.

Answer (score 1):

`su` is not a shell built-in. You have to specify an absolute path to su in the "Executable" property:

```
/bin/su
```

Then, to call "actualExecutable with the argument "argument" as the user "guest", you set the "Arguments" property of the "Run executable or batch file" action to

```
guest;-c;actualExecutable;argument
```

Comment: OK, I'm a dummy.  Thank you!  I had another place where I did want to run a shell built-in but couldn't.  If that comes up again I'll post another question.

Comment: You would do that by invoking the executable `/bin/sh` with arguments `-c;builtin;arguments`